# Remove images from Listview Columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

For the columns in a `ListView` I am using my own Images to show if the sorting is ascending or descending. When I set the `column.ImageKey` property the column's text is moved to the right to make room for an image. The problem I'm having is how to remove the Image when I don't need it anymore. By setting the `column.ImageKey = ""` and `column.ImageIndex = -1` I remove the Image, but the text isn't on it's starting position. So basically I just reset the Image Objects bitmap but I don't remove the Image Object itself. So I'm wondering how to remove/disable the Image Object.

Comment: Yes it is for a Windows Form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove image from column you need to restore default text alignment of your column after you removed image:

```
column.ImageIndex = -1;
column.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

Why it helped? Because when you are assigning image index >= 0 to column header, internally following method is called

```
ListView.SetColumnInfo(0x10, column);
```

Which changes text alignment of column

```
lParam.iImage = column.ActualImageIndex_Internal;
lParam.fmt |= 0x800;
lParam.fmt |= column.TextAlign;
UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, Handle), 
     NativeMethods.LVM_SETCOLUMN, column.Index, lParam);
```

But it does not change alignment back when you are setting image index to -1.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have the time to explain why this solved my problem?

Answer (score 2):

With a slight change in Sergey Berezovskiy answer, when you have different Text Alignments per column, you can also do;

```
column.ImageIndex = -1;
column.TextAlign = column.TextAlign;
```